# Non-Editable NSButton-CheckBox

Tags: cocoa, checkbox, nsbutton

I have an NSButton styled as a check box and I'd like to deny the user from changing the state if a certain condition is true but NSButton does not have a `setEditable:` method and the `setEnabled:` method greys out the control. Is there any way to make achieve this functionality  or are there alternative ways to represent data usually represented by checkboxes?

Comment: It seems like greying out the control when it's disabled is appropriate. Otherwise, how is the user to know that they can't manipulate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide this functionality I attached an IBAction to the check-box that "resets" the check-box's value i.e. if the check-box is on when the user clicks on it is set to on.

Answer (score 0):

Denying the user to check a checkbox is exactly the same as with pressing a button. You use the setEnabled method to deny or allow a user to check your checkbox.

Your snippet of code would kind of look like this:

```
if(condition for deny is met) 
{
    [myCheckBox setEnabled:NO];
}else
{
    [myCheckBox setEnabled: YES];
}
```

You'll see that it works with every button, including your checkbox.